# Where to find groovy library on intellij(mac) when installed groovy through sdkman

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, sdkman

I installed groovy through sdkman on mac. When i try to create a new groovy project in intellij, it asks for groovy library location. Where can i find the installed groovy?

Comment: Normally it should be under `/users/<username>/.sdkman/groovy/current` or `/users/<username>/.sdkman/groovy/<version>`. Mark that `.sdkman` might not be visible in IntelliJ by default, but tracing through the directory structure should be possible.

Comment: @dmahapatro you are right. It is not visible. It is in /Users/Ramisetti/.sdkman/candidates/groovy. Thank you.

Comment: Whenever you have this problem, use the `which` shell command. `which groovy` will tell you the answer

Comment: I suggest you don't use `current` in the project config in IntelliJ as that will change which GDK it points to over time.  Rather use `/Users/<username>/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/<version>` for the specific version your project needs.

Answer (score 25):

I ran into similar issue. By using

```
/Users/<username/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current
```

or

```
/Users/<username/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/<version>
```

worked for me.

Comment: <cmd><shift><.> allows you to pick the hidden folder in the open dialog box.

Comment: CMD+SHIFT+G also appears to work and was the solution recommended by JetBrains.

Answer (score 15):

Adding the answer that solved my problem (thanks to [ThomasW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3252543/thomasw) comment)

When dialog box is opened you can click <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>
and this allows you to pick the hidden folder in the open dialog box.

[image]

Then you can use:

```
/Users/<username>/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current
```

Comment: @Downvoter, any helpful explanation to improve the answer?

Answer (score 6):

Just run `$ which groovy` after have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to find groovy path with `which` command.
After installation of sdkman on linux-like systems Mac OSX, Linux, Cygwin, Solaris and FreeBSD,
 First, run `$ source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"`, then you will be able to access the installed development kits.

Namely, if you type `'which groovy'` it should show the path, and you can invoke other SDK commands.